# Leaflet remove layer vue3

Tags: javascript, leaflet, vuejs3, pinia

I have a map that displays json data, and a radio button that changes de FL of the displayed data. The problem that I have is that every time I change the Fl I am not able to remove the previous layer and it just overlays the previous one. I have tried the code below, but is not working. The new_storm_layer is stored in a Store created with pinia.

```
function create_map_layer(geojson_data, maptoplot) {
        //maptoplot.eachLayer((new_layer) => {
        //  layer.remove();
        //});
        const new_layer = leaflet.geoJSON(geojson_data).addTo(maptoplot)
        new_layer.clearLayers();
        new_layer.addData(geojson_data);
        return new_layer
      }

      async function foo(get_request) {
        await fetch(get_request
        ).then(
          res => res.json()
        ).then(
          data => create_map_layer(data, mymap)
        ).then(
          new_storm_layer => DataStore.$patch({ storm_layer: new_storm_layer })
        )
      }
```

Thank you in advance!

Described above, removing previous layers.